# Adding MimeMap via WIX failed

Tags: wix, mime

I've been given a bug to fix an installer issue.  Unfortunately, I know nothing about WIX, so I am not exactly where to start.

The WXS file is adding the necessary MimeMap, but when QA installed our app on Windows 2003 with IIS6, the MIME type was not set.

I am not sure where to start.  We are using Wix 3.0.  Here is the XML:

```
<iis:WebSite Id="DefaultWebSite" Description="Default Web Site">
  <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="80" />
  <iis:MimeMap Id="registerXapMimeType" Extension=".xap" Type="application/x-silverlight-app"/>
</iis:WebSite>
```

Any idea to why this MIME type was not mapped?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm doing almost the same thing and it's working; the only difference I can see is I'm setting it under the WebVirtualDir instead of WebSite element:

```
<Component Id="IIS6VirtualDirComponent" KeyPath="yes" Guid="blah">
  <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="IIS6VirtualDir" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION" Alias="[TARGETVDIR]" WebSite="IIS6WebSite" DirProperties="IIS6WebDirProperties">
    <iis:WebApplication Id="IIS6WebApplication" Name="[TARGETVDIR]" WebAppPool="IIS6WebAppPool">
    ...
    </iis:WebApplication>
    <iis:MimeMap Id="IIS6MimeMapXAP" Extension=".xap" Type="application/x-silverlight-app" />
  </iis:WebVirtualDir>
</Component>
```

Comment: This seems to add the MIME types to the virtual application, within a web site. What about adding the MIME types to the web site itself?

Answer (score 1):

same problem here, trying a custom action. 
I also tried putting the  inside the   node but that didn't work either.

for more details: 
[Is there a way to get ALL the MIME types instead of wrinting a huge case statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191811/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-the-mime-types-instead-of-wrinting-a-huge-case-statemen/1767242#1767242)

Answer (score 1):

Brian, I fixed this by moving the MimeMap registration to the WebVirtualDir as suggested by Si. Go figure...