# Add MIME type to IIS web site using WiX

Tags: wix, mime-types, wix-iisextension

I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817782/1061602), but this just adds the MIME types to the virtual application, not to the web site itself.

According to WiX documentation for [MimeMap element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/iis/mimemap.html), MimeMap has two parents, WebSite and WebVirtualDir, so it should be able to be applied to the web site, however it doesn't seem to do anything. Also I cannot see anything in the logs to indicate why it has failed.

How can I get the WiX installer to add the MIME types to the web site instead?

Code:

```
<!-- configure iis -->
<Component Id="CMP_iisConfig" Guid="MY_GUID_HERE" KeyPath="yes">

    <!-- configure application pool -->
    <iis:WebAppPool Id="APPPOOL" Name="[APP_POOL_NAME]" ManagedPipelineMode="integrated"/>

    <!-- configure web site -->
    <iis:WebSite Id="WEBSITE" Description="[WEBSITE_NAME]" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">

        <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="[PORT]"/>   

        <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="VIRTUALDIR" Alias="[VIRTUAL_APP_ALIAS]" Directory="API">
            <!-- configure virtual application -->
            <iis:WebApplication Id="APP" Name="[VIRTUAL_APP_NAME]" WebAppPool="APPPOOL" />
        </iis:WebVirtualDir>

        <!-- configure mime types -->
        <iis:MimeMap Id="MIME_JSON" Extension=".json" Type="application/json" />

    </iis:WebSite>                
</Component>
```

Answer (score -1):

Putting MimeMap inside the WebVirtualDir tag should solve the issue.