# Opening FileTable Files in c# / .net 4

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-2012, filetable

I have a Filetable containing many different document types (.doc;.pdf;.xls etc).

I am writing a small web (C# / .net 4) search app. Search works great using fulltext index with filetable to find content.

But I'm struggling to find a way in my app to have the search results as links which can launch the document in question? And just handle the different file types? (Assume client has Word/adobe/excel installed etc)

Grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write a custom page handler to stream the bytes to the client with the proper HTTP headers. You will need to decide whether to support inline viewing (*open in the browser - `Content-Disposition: inline`*) versus external viewing using an attachment (*e.g. `Content-Disposition: attachment`*).

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=example.pdf");
```

If you are using ASP.NET MVC - you can leverage the [`FileResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to streamline this process, but creating your own handler wouldn't be too much different.

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = ...; // from FileTable
    string fileName = "example.txt";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

The best approach to handling various MIME types (PDF, DOC, XLS) is to statically define the supported file types or dynamically [read IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192588/175679) and assign the appropriate `Content-Type` HTTP header.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
```

Comment: very useful - thank you - using this in combination with the filetable file_stream column to get the data and actually using Response.BinaryWrite to open file in browser. Thanks!